# Today is my last day at work but my colleagues don't know about it

Tags: resignation, team, quitting, notice-period

I am leaving my job after just 6 months because of strong dissatisfaction with working conditions, and today is my last date at work and end of my notice period too.

Last time an employee left the company, CEO of our startup announced it a week before in Monday morning meeting, and also wished him success for his future, along with a small present from the company.

But since I am leaving very soon, they have not even publicly announced it. CEO is also not at office today, so no chance of it either today. It's a small company (~20 peoples) but none of my colleagues except 3-4 knows today is my last day.

I am wondering what should do I about it? I am introvert so I don't mind leaving in evening casually without bringing it. But what is the right approach about this? Ideally I don't want to go to everyone desk to announce I am leaving.

Comment: I don't understand, you said you dont mind leaving without bringing it up. Depends if you have any friendships in the company but those people probably already know so just leave

Comment: @Twyxz Yeah my department (6/20 people) know this. I was wondering if I am supposed to tell the others.

Comment: You're leaving because of the working condition, so isn't their lack of care in your leaving a property of the working condition you dislike?

Comment: Can you clarify your goal? You said, *"What should I do about it?"* which is a hard question to answer without knowing what you're trying to accomplish: you seem to hint that you're an introvert and don't care if people know, but you also seem compelled to tell people.

Comment: @Dan Yeah! Pretty much. Even my boss didn't bothered to wish me good luck with future or whatever. Even thought I worked my best even during notice period. My work was exceptional till my last day.

Comment: @dwizum Yeah! Pretty much. I personally don't care. But still want to do what I am supposed to do. Day is finally over and it went well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I work in a larger company than yours (hundreds of employee, not dozens), but my department size can be expressed in dozens.

Whenever a person leaves, he/she typically emails a bunch of people (usually in bcc) a nice leaving message containing something related to the pleasant experience within the company and some personal contact information (usually an e-mail address).

Optionally, leaving the company is marked by a small lunch for close colleagues (e.g. pizza, pies, nothing fancy).

I do not like to find out that a person just "disappeared" from the department. So, this might also be the case for some of your co-workers. If you worked closely with some of your colleagues and some bonds were created, it would be nice for them to know before it is actually happening.

I am also an introvert and I am not into end of job parties (or parties in general), but when I had to leave, I announced the colleagues I worked with + a pizza/pie. It was a pleasant experience and most of the colleagues encouraged me about the future job.

Also, CEO's announcement of your leaving should be secondary, since it is more about you and your colleagues.

Comment: I will send an email to team to everyone in few hours. I've tried to talk to my department (6 peoples). But I don't know how to bring it to everyone without sounding like attracting attention (esp since CEO is pissed with me for resigning and took it personally). Will a slack message about last day in #general channel is enough along with a good bye personally while leaving in evening?

Comment: @NotAQuitter It depends, does everyone use Slack? And I wouldn't worry about looking like you are trying to attract attention - everyone will know tomorrow anyway. If you really don't want to be around when a mass message is sent, do it as the last thing before you walk out the door, or use your email client to set up a delayed send for the evening.

Comment: @DavidK Yes. Everyone use slack. I was going to send the message in an hour (around afternoon). But HR person just approached me and said they want to keep it secret. I don't know what she mean by "secret" but I'm not sure if I even allowed to say good bye anymore :/

Comment: @NotAQuitter Have you asked HR why they want it a secret? Today is your last day, correct? If you don't keep it a secret, what are they going to do, fire you? My guess is that there is a lot of unrest, and they don't want other people asking you why you left or where you're going.

Comment: @DavidK Yes! She said they don't want gossips. I guess I should professionally tell anyone without badmouthing the company. I hope I will be fine.

Comment: @NotAQuitter My point is that if you want to let everyone know you are leaving and perhaps share your contact information in case anyone wants to stay in touch, there's not much HR can do to stop you.

Comment: @NotAQuitter - it is almost impossible to stop gossip no matter what you do, so don't bother about that. Also, you are right that it is not professionally to badmouth the company, especially when you are still there.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks. I used Slack to give a heads up to everyone. And in evening just announced when I left. Since everybody knew today is my last day, they greeted me and I don't had to go t o everyone desk either.